# Android : Entries cannot be protected with passwords

Tags: java, android, security, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to store a keypair into Android's keystore. So far, i have this test code :

```
KeyPairGenerator keygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keygen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keypair = keygen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey priv = keypair.getPrivate();
PublicKey pub = keypair.getPublic();
String passwd = "Insert some strong password here.";
Certificate[] certChain = new Certificate[1];
certChain[0] = generateCertificate(keypair);
ks.setKeyEntry("test", priv, passwd.toCharArray(), certChain);
```

The `generateCertificate` method is using Bouncy Castle library.

When i run this code, i get a `java.security.KeyStoreException: entries cannot be protected with passwords`

Which is stange, since `setKeyEntry` do have a password argument.
How can i get rid of this ? And is using a strong-string password stored in app's source code safe ?

Thanks.

Comment: A password stored in the source is never safe, does not matter if it is strong or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently despite the fact that the method takes a password parameter, the `AndroidKeystore` implementation does not support this, take a look at line 200 in [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/keystore/java/android/security/AndroidKeyStore.java).

In any case, a password, whether strong or weak that is stored anywhere on the device is unsafe.  This is *especially* true of source code (including source code in general, non-android contexts).  If I get my hands on your app's APK, I can use one of several excellent APK analysis tools to access the class's constant pool, which will contain the password in plain text.  No amount of obfuscation could prevent this, or even make it more difficult.  This is perhaps the reason that the `AndroidKeystore` implementation doesn't allow this.

The whole point of the key store service on android device (it's actually implemented as a separate process you can talk to via a unix socket) is to protect access to sensitive material by requiring a users passcode to unlock it, so there's no point in putting a password on your key pairs or other secrets..  In more recent phones, this is all implmented in hardware, which provides very strong security.

Comment: Got it, no harcoded password. I re-build a solution, right here : http://pastebin.com/ay4VwRX6
This is a safer one, isn't it ?

Comment: @Rogue, it's safer in that you're no longer hardcoding a password, yes.  But to really say whether it's actually safe in general, I'd have to know more about what you're going to do with the key.

Comment: Oh, Well I'll use it to encrypt strings, and send encrypted datas to a server. (and thanks for answering btw :))

Comment: What if I have this scenario ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548551/how-to-generate-keypair-in-android-keystore-protected-by-custom-password . This way my keypair password will not be stored in apk, it will be entered by user. How can I apply password protection?